# What I can do to make the point colour translucid in two plots overlaped?

Tags: gnuplot, alpha-transparency

I have overlap two plots which are composed by multiple points.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwJz.png .

Now I'm trying to make the points of the green plot translucid to see if they are indeed overlapped. I have tried to modify the rgb alpha channels (0xaa00ff00) to make the colour translucid and/or the command:

set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder

but with no luck.

The Gnuplot (version 5.4) input is the following:

```
set terminal pngcairo truecolor size 1000,1000 enhanced font 'Helvetica,20'
set encoding iso_8859_1
set output 'prova4.png'
unset clip points
set clip one
unset clip two
set border 31 front lt -1 lw 1.0
set format x "% g"
set format y "% g"
set format cb "% g"
unset grid
set key title ""
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitles nobox
set key noinvert samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0
set key maxcolumns 0 maxrows 0
set key noopaque
set offsets 0, 0, 0, 0
set pointsize 1
set pointintervalbox 1
unset polar
unset parametric
unset decimalsign
set xlabel 'sign({/Symbol l}_2){/Symbol r}(a.u.)' font "Helvetica, 30"
set xlabel  offset character 0, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set ylabel 's(a.u.)' font "Helvetica, 30"
set ylabel  offset character 0, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set yrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set cblabel ""
set cblabel  offset character 0, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
plot 'a.dat' lc rgb '#0x80ff0000' t 'A', 'b.dat' lc rgb '#0x8000ff00' t 'B'
```

¿What I can do to make the color translucid?

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? If yes, please select the accept mark next to the answer indicating that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer yourself, but you did not apply it. Try:

```
plot 'a.dat' lc rgb 0xaaff0000 t 'A', 'b.dat' lc rgb 0xaa00ff00 t 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said above, I have tried with the rgb alpha channels but with no luck. It seems I have forgotten to write in the code. Sorry. I have edit the code.

Comment: @JuanVelasquez Please check my answer in detail. It is not `rgb '#0x80ff0000'` but `rgb 0xaaff0000`. Mind: no `''` and no `#`.